# Add CCS class based on variable from user model

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the below user model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    filename: String
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    username: String,
    dateofbirth:Date,
    status: Boolean,
    images: [ImageSchema],
},{ timestamps: true });

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I want to update the below css based on the value of the users status. If Status = true then add a class of .test1; if the Status = false then dont add a class and leave blank.

```
<div id="statususername">
 <h5 class="btn-outline-secondary test1">Gold</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a javascript file that gets the element using `document.querySelector('.my-class')` and then adding or removing the class for example

```js
let myEl = document.querySelector('.my-class');
if(status) {
    myEl.classList.add("test1")
} else {
   myEl.classList.remove("test1")
}
```

of course, just pasting this somewhere won't work you need to call that as a function when needed and pass in the status which you'd have to fetch from the server. the other option is server-side rendering for example if you use EJS (a
templating engine) you can generate the HTML to have or not have the desired class.

EJS Docs: [Docs](https://ejs.co/#docs) 
EJS tutorial with node: [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

finally, if you were to use React you could use state and a ternary operator but if you're fairly far into a project it's rather difficult to switch to React without a fair bit of effort so I would recommend grabbing the element with javascript and setting the classList depending on a variable grabbed from the server using AJAX or using a templating engine

Use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and frontend JS if you need to update the class list at some point instead of just setting it once

Use a templating engine like [EJS](https://ejs.co/#docs) if you need to add the class once when the page is rendered